# How to setup SQL Developer database connection when remote server uses smartcard authentication

Tags: ssh, oracle-sqldeveloper, smartcard, cac

I connect to my remote server via smartcard authentication using PuTTy-CAC. I am prompted for a pin number everytime I want to connect to my Linux server. Once I am logged in I can access my database via Sqlplus.

I am having trouble setting up the connection in SQL Developer. Is their a way I can get SQL Developer to use my smartcard authentication. I created a SSH tunnel but no luck. I get this error below:

[image]

I have tried creating an SSH host and port forward but was unsuccessful.

I can't find any information regarding smartcard authentication for SQL Developer.

Comment: Can you create the putty tunnel with the pin and then comnect through that vs our built in ssh tunnel?...so basically same you're doing with sqlplus

Comment: But how do I get sql developer to use my PUTTY connection ? I create the tunnel via Putty? and Sql developer will automatically detect ?

Comment: no automatically detecting, something like this but only with your putty connection, how are you getting local sqlplus to go across the putty tunnel? https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/ssh-tunnel

Comment: I access sqlplus by connecting to the remote server via putty-cac first. So once I create the putty tunnel how do I get SQL Developer to recognize that I have established the tunnel? Thats the part that I am confused about, how will SQL Developer know that I have a putty tunnel setup? I can't find any examples.

Comment: Have one end of your tunnel on your machine and a local portz connect through that

Comment: So I got my SSH Hosts is SQL Developer to say "Connection Test successful" but when I try to connect to the DB I get this error: Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call. What does this mean ?